# Converting text to dataset parameters: Union of an object and the category to which it belongs

Tags: python

**A task:**
You need to open the parentheses combined category and the object that belongs to it.
The combination of categories means that we have a category and its objects, for example genre (rock, pop, hip-hop) needs to be converted to genre_rock, genre_pop, genre_hip-hop. At the input and output of the code is a string, just during operation it is converted into a list.
The purpose of the code is to clear one of the dataset parameters to work with the recommender system.

**Question:**
What parts of the code can be optimized so that it works faster + does not look ugly?

**Example:**

1. `'Category (first ,second (1,2))` -> `'Category_first,Category_second_1,Category_second_2'`
2. `'Category (first ,second)'` -> `'Category_first,Category_second'`

**Code:**

```py
def i_par_find(text, i_par_l):
    l_r = 0
    i_par_r = i_par_l
    for s in text[i_par_r:]:
        if s == '(':
            l_r += 1
        elif s == ')':
            l_r -= 1
        i_par_r += 1
        if l_r == 0:
            return i_par_l, i_par_r
​
def glue_list(text, i_par_l, i_par_r, i_comma):
    word_list = re.sub(r'[()]', '',
                       text[i_par_l:i_par_r]).replace(' ', '_').split(",")
    word_list = [w.strip('_') for w in word_list]
    category = text[i_comma:i_par_l].strip()
    list_word = []
    for w in word_list:
        if w != '':
            list_word.append(f'{category}_{w}')
    return ",".join(list_word)
​
def list_w(text):
    # If there is no comma, the category search starts at index 0.
    i_comma = 0
    # Index
    i = 0
​
    while i < len(text) - 1:
        # Select a specific character in the text.
        i += 1
        s = text[i]
​
        # Step 1: save the last comma before the parenthesis
        if s == ',': i_comma = i
​
        # Step 2: Check for "("
        if s == '(':
            # Step 3: Look up the index of the leading "(" and closing ")", nested parentheses are ignored.
            i_par_l, i_par_r = i_par_find(text, i)
​
            # If a comma is inside brackets, then its index is set to zero.
            if i_comma >= i_par_l and i_comma <= i_par_r:
                i_comma = 0
​
            # If there is "(" inside the found slice, then we use recursion
            if '(' in text[i_par_l + 1:i_par_r - 1]:
                text = text[:i_par_l + 1] + list_w(
                    text[i_par_l + 1:i_par_r - 1]) + text[i_par_r - 1:]
​
            # If processing text doesn't start at 0, add 1 to index to capture comma.
            if i_comma != 0: i_comma += 1

​            # Adding a comma depending on the position of the processed area in the text
            c_or_n = ''
            if i_par_r <= len(text) and text[i_par_r - 1] == ',': c_or_n = ','
​
            # Step 4: Connect parameters and categories, with text before and after the treated area.
            text = text[:i_comma] + glue_list(
                text, i_par_l, i_par_r, i_comma) + c_or_n + text[i_par_r:]
​
    text = re.sub(r'[()]', '', text)
    return text

list_w(text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to parse the string character by character, mutating the text as you go along.

```
def list_w(text):
    ...
    i = 0
​
    while i < len(text) - 1:
        i += 1
        s = text[i]
        ...
                text = text[:i_par_l + 1] + list_w(
                    text[i_par_l + 1:i_par_r - 1]) + text[i_par_r - 1:]
​        ...
    text = re.sub(r'[()]', '', text)
    return text
```

I find it extremely hard to reason about this code.

A clearer algorithm could be to work from the inside out.  With `'Category (first ,second (1,2))'`, find the innermost category pattern `second (1,2)` and replace that with `second_1, second_2`, producing `'Category (first ,second_1, second_2)'`.  Since there are more parenthesis, repeat, which produces the desired result.

Finding the innermost category pattern starts with looking for text which does not contain parenthesis `[^()]+`, but is surrounded by them, `\( ... \)`.  We also need to find a "word" before that, possibly with some trailing space: `\b \w+ \s*`.

To that regex, we'll add capturing groups `(...)` to extract the term before the parenthesis and well as inside. `\b(\w+)\s*\(([^()]+)\)`

Now all that is left to do it split on any commas in the second group, strip off spaces, and add the first group as a prefix to each term.  Join the result with commas, and replace what what originally matched.  Repeat until there are no more parenthesis.

```
import re

def categories(s):
    def expand(m):
        prefix, suffixes = m.groups()
        return ",".join(f"{prefix}_{suffix}"
                        for suffix in map(str.strip, suffixes.split(",")))

    while '(' in s:
        s = re.sub(r"\b(\w+)\s*\(([^()]+)\)", expand, s)

    return s

s = 'Category (first ,second (1,2))'

print(categories(s))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll go learn regular expressions

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that you are solving this at the wrong level. Trying to do it character-by-character makes it much more difficult than it needs to be. You are already using the `re` module to replace '(' and ')' with spaces. Why not use it to "tokenize" the input string (You could also use the `tokenize` module).

The input string is made up of names, parenthesis, and commas. This regex would break return a list of these pieces:

```
tokens = re.findall(r"\s*(\w+|[(,)])", text)
```

Then we can operate with those pieces to assemble the categories.

```
def flatten(source):
    # This is the prefix of the current subcategory if any.
    # It is a string of names joined by '_'.
    path = ''
    
    tokens = pat.findall(source)
    while tokens:
        # pick off the next token
        token, *tokens = tokens
        
        if token.isalnum():
            name = token
            
        # If there is an '(' then there must be subcategories. So, add
        # the current name to the "path"
        elif token == '(':
            path = f"{path}_{name}" if path else name
            
        # A ',' ends the current subcategory. Yield the entire flattened
        # category name. The 'if name:' guard prevents yielding multiple 
        # copies of a subcategory when there are ")," and "))"
        elif token == ',':
            if name:
                yield f"{path}_{name}"
            name = ''

        # a ')' ends the list of subcategories. Yield the flattened
        # category name. Also remove the parent from the 'path'. Same 
        # guard as for the ',' above.
        elif token == ')':
            if name:
                yield f"{path}_{name}"

            path,_,_ = path.rpartition('_')
            name = ''
```

Use it like so:

```
text = "Category (first (alpha, bravo), second (1))"
print(','.join(flatten(text)))
```

Output:

```
Category_first_alpha,Category_first_bravo,Category_second_1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a pity that I can't mark two solutions at once.